# Recursion that branches running out of memory

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

I have a programming assignment that goes like this:

You are given three numbers a, b, and c. (1 ≤ а, b, c ≤ 10^18)
Each time you have two choises, either add b to a (a+=b), or add a to b (b+=a). Write a program that will print out YES or NO depending on whether you can get to c by adding a and b to each other.

I've tried solving this problem using recursion that branches to two branches every time where one branch stores a+b, b and the other branch stores a, b+a. In every recursive call, the function checks the values of a and b, and if they are equal to c the search stops and the function prints YES. The recursion stops when either a or b have a value greater than c.

Here's how the branching works:
[image]

And here's the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void tree(long long int a, long long int b, long long int c){
    if(a==c || b==c){
        printf("YES");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(a<c && b<c){
        tree(a, b+a, c);
        tree(a+b, b, c);
    }
}

int main(){
    long long int a, b, c;
    scanf("%I64d", &a);
    scanf("%I64d", &b);
    scanf("%I64d", &c);

    tree(a, b, c);

    printf("NO");

    return 0;
}
```

Now, this program works for small numbers, but since a b and c can be any 64-bit number, the tree can branch itself a few billion times, and the program runs out of memory and crashes.

My question is: Is there any way i can improve my code, or use any other way (other then recursion) to solve this?

Comment: What you're really evaluating is whether there are integer constants `x` and `y`, such that `x*a + y*b == c`.

Comment: Have you thought about if there is *no* solution to some numbers? Then your recursion would just continue forever anyway.

Comment: There is a mistake in the third level it should be 3,10.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the recursion stops when one of the numbers a or b gets bigger than c.

Comment: @Madan, yes, I made the image in a short time, didn't double check it

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Or the solution may require deep enough recursion to overflow the stack -- potentially to overflow ANY stack. Recursion is often ***not*** the best way to code something; even when it is, it can often be done much more efficiently with a loop and explicitly managed stacks than with call/return.

Comment: "c ≤ 2^64" is going to be hard to achieve without 128 bit `int`. With 64-bit, which should be `unsigned`, even if the limit is "c < 2^64" you would have to detect integer overflow (wrap-round).

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, my mistake, it isn't 2^64, it is 10^18 which should be achiveable with 64 bits.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried solving the problem this way, but it is not quite correct. For example if you take a=5, b=6, c=22, you can express c like 22=2*5+2*6, but if you start using the a+=b and b+=a rules from the problem, you won't get to 22. Here's the tree as well: http://oi58.tinypic.com/21dizbq.jpg

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth is correct that you are trying to find `x` and `y` such that `x*a + y*b == c`, but there is an additional restriction that `gcd(x,y) == 1`. In other words, `x` must be relatively prime to `y`.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, that's correct, do you by any chance have the mathematical explanation why that is? A friend of mine told me this hint, but he didn't explain to me why it is so.

Comment: @DavidSimka I'm afraid I can't prove it mathematically. I found it experimentally by creating a 16x16 reachability matrix, and observing the patterns. For example, if you have 3A's, then the matrix is missing 3,6,9,12,15 B's. You can create the matrix by running your tree algorithm to a depth of 16, while keeping track of the numbers of As and Bs (as opposed to adding hard-coded numbers).

Comment: @user3386109 this should help [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c)

Answer (score 4):

OK I'll have to admit that this turned out to be a fascinating question.  I really thought that there should be a quick way of finding out the answer but the more I looked at the problem, the more complex it became.  For example, if you zigzag down the tree, alternating `a+=b` with `b+=a`, you are essentially creating the fibonacci sequence (imagine a=2 and b=3 to start with).  Which means that if you could find the answer quickly, you could somehow use a similar program to answer "is `c` a fibonacci number"?

So I never came up with anything better than searching the binary tree.  But I did come up with a way to search the binary tree without running out of memory.  The key trick in my algorithm is that at every node you need to search two child nodes.  But you don't need to recurse down both paths.  You only need to recurse down one path, and if that fails, you can iterate to the other child.  When recursing, you should always pick the path where the smaller number changes.  This guarantees that you are doubling the minimum element on each recursion level, which guarantees that you will only recurse 64 times max before your minimum element will exceed 2^64.

So I wrote the program and ran it, and it worked just fine.  That is until I entered a very large number for `c`.  At that point, it didn't finish.  I found from testing that the algorithm appears to have an O(N^2) running time, where N = c.  Here are some sample running times (all on a desktop running 64-bit Windows).

```
Inputs                              Time in minutes
------                              ---------------
a=2   b=3   c=10000000000  (10^10):  0:20
a=2   b=3   c=100000000000 (10^11): 13:42
a=2   b=3   c=100000000001        :  2:21 (randomly found the answer quickly)
a=2   b=3   c=100000000002        : 16:36
a=150 b=207 c=10000000     (10^7) :  0:08 (no solution)
a=150 b=207 c=20000000            :  0:31 (no solution)
a=150 b=207 c=40000000            :  2:05 (no solution)
a=150 b=207 c=100000000    (10^8) : 12:48 (no solution)
```

Here is my code:

```c
// Given three numbers: a, b, c.
//
// At each step, either do: a += b, or b += a.
// Can you make either a or b equal to c?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int solve(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    if (argc < 4) {
        printf("Usage: %s a b c\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    a = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    b = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    c = strtoull(argv[3], NULL, 0);

    // Note, by checking to see if a or b are solutions here, solve() can
    // be made simpler by only checking a + b == c.  That speeds up solve().
    if (a == c || b == c || solve(a, b, c))
        printf("There is a solution\n");
    else
        printf("There is NO solution\n");
    return 0;
}

int solve(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c)
{
    do {
        uint64_t sum = a + b;
        // Check for past solution.
        if (sum > c)
            return 0;
        // Check for solution.
        if (sum == c)
            return 1;
        // The algorithm is to search both branches (a += b and b += a).
        // But first we search the branch where add the higher number to the
        // lower number, because that branch will be guaranteed to double the
        // lower number, meaning we will not recurse more than 64 times.  Then
        // if that doesn't work out, we iterate to the other branch.
        if (a < b) {
            // Try a += b recursively.
            if (solve(sum, b, c))
                return 1;
            // Failing that, try b += a.
            b = sum;
        } else {
            // Try b += a recursively.
            if (solve(a, sum, c))
                return 1;
            // Failing that, try a += b.
            a = sum;
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

Edit: I optimized the above program by removing recursion, reordering the arguments so that `a` is always less than `b` at every step, and some more tricks.  It runs about 50% faster than before.  You can find [the optimized program here](https://github.com/Jsdemonsim/Stackoverflow/blob/master/addnum.c).

Comment: Thank you man, it is a nice improvement on my initial idea to solve it with recursion, but since the time limit for my homework is 1 second, it still fails on time with some of the bigger cases.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment from @Oliver Charlesworth, this is an iterative not recursive solution so it won't solve the homework. But it's pretty simple, I step through `b` because it is larger than `a` (although that is not entirely clear from the OP) hence fewer iterations required.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long long int a, b, c, bb;
    scanf("%I64u", &a);
    scanf("%I64u", &b);
    scanf("%I64u", &c);

    if (a >= 1 && a < b && b < c) {
        for (bb=b; bb<c; bb+=b) {
            if ((c - bb) % a == 0) {
                printf ("YES\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Try a=5, b=6, c=27.  One solution is 5,6 -> 5,11 -> 16,11 -> 27,11.  But your program would say no because 27%6%5 = 3, 27%12%5=3, 27%18%5=4, and 27%24%5=3.

Comment: It should probably be if ((c - bb) % a == 0), but anyways thanks, I tried making a similar solution as well, but I am still having some problems, gonna try yours now.

Comment: @JS1 good hit, thanks. `3*5 + 2*6 = 27` satisfies the @Oliver Charlesworth comment at the top, but I can't yet see why my answer doesn't get it.

Comment: @DavidSimka thank you the edit as per your comment is better now.

Comment: Now, a=5, b=6, c=22 returns YES, but there is no way of reaching 22, so the answer should be NO.

Comment: Doesn't 10 + 12 = 22?

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes it is, but that is not the correct way of solving the main problem (that I explained in the OP).

The same problem happens with a=5, b=8, c=46. 46=2*8+3*5 but if you do the tree with branching (the image in the OP) you will not get to 46.

Comment: Yes I see that now (but not blame the very first comment that launched me!) and it's an interesting question.

Comment: @WeatherVane I still think that binary tree is the way to go, but I haven't had much experience with them to make an efficient one.