# C program using recursion need to get optimised and fixed

Tags: c, optimization, recursion, integer, long-long

I was solving a task that was - a user is entering 3 numbers, `a, b, c`. The goal is to find if you can get to `c` summing `a` and `b`. In each step is allowed to add `a` to `b`, and `b` to `a`. I need to find if that is possible with the entered numbers. The entered numbers are in the range between `0` and `10^18`. Below is my code, done with recursion.

Example of solving the task for `a=4 b=6 c=38`:

1. `a=4 b=10`
2. `a=14 b=10`
3. `a=14 b=24`
4. `a=38 b=24 print YES`

My code below does its job well for low numbers but I think I'm loosing the battle with the bigger numbers... I added few comments to what part is doing what.

What I need help is, I need it to work better, and faster, and I don't know how to optimise it more.

```
//the function that I'm using
int task(long long int a, long long int b, long long int c, long long int d, int p) 
{ //a, b and c are long long integers that are submited by the user, d is the sum of
  //the unchanged a and b, and p is a flag
    if(!a && !b && c) return 0; //0+0 will never get to 1
    if(c==d) return 1; //if I get with c to d, it is confirmed yes, 
                       //did the math with a pen :)
    if(c<d || c<=0) // I thought this is a nice case to stop
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(p==1)
    {
        if(a>c) return 0; //if the flag p is one, that means i changed a, 
                          //so compare a
    }
    if(p==2)
    {
        if(b>c) return 0; //if p is two, i changed b so compare b
    }
    if(c-d>0) return task(a+b, b, c-b, d, 1)||task(a, b+a, c-a, d, 2);  
            //recursion call with OR operator so every step is checked

}//one part is a=a+b b=b c=c-b, i decrement c so fewer steps are needed, 
 //the other part is when i add a to b

int main()
{
    long long int a,b,c;
    scanf("%I64d%I64d%I64d",&a,&b,&c); //scaning
    int p; //the flag for the first numbers
    if(a>b) p=1; //i dont know if i need this step at all xD
    else p=2; //but to make sure
    if((a==1 || b==1) && c) printf("YES"); //a=1 b=1 and c>=1 means i can get to c,
                                           //even with a+b+b+b..
    else if(a==c || b==c) printf("YES"); //if one of the numbers are already same 
                                         //with c, no need to check
    else if(task(a,b,c,a+b,p)) printf("YES"); //if the function returns 1, print YES
    else printf("NO"); //or print NO


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd focus more on improving your algorithm. I feel like its probable there is some number theory principle you can use to turn this into an iteration instead of a recursion.  It may also just call for Dynamic Programming, which I wish I understood better myself.

Comment: @Galvanic Is it to find c with multiples of a and b or is it whether c is in the ascension of a sequence of a, b, a+b, a+a+b, a+a+b+b, a+a+a+b+b, etc.?

Comment: @George Houpis, no it's not n x a + m x b, this question has been asked recently as tree recursion but I can't yet find it.

Comment: The problem with the previous same question, was not how to solve it, but how to prevent it running out of stack space.

Comment: @Galvanic Previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335684/recursion-that-branches-running-out-of-memory/27336342#27336342

Comment: @WeatherVane In fact that is the same task but I dont really see a solution yet...

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis it is in the ascension of a sequence like you wrote there, it is kind of like search through a tree and find the right branch

Comment: @Galvanic I've provided a hint in the comment section of the other thread.

Comment: Is there an error in the tree picture in the other thread?  (3,11) should be (3,10) right?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis - yes, that's an error.

Comment: In that other thread, the problem is solved already. I have to write iteration, recursion obv. fails to do it's job

Comment: @Galvanic - I don't think the problem is really solved in that question. A really good solution hasn't been posted to either question, and a really good solution solves both questions.

Comment: [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c)

Answer (score 0):

> My code below does its job well for low numbers

It doesn't. Try input `2 2 3`. The most obvious error is:

```
In function 'main':
 warning: format '%I64d' expects type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'long long int *'
 warning: format '%I64d' expects type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'long long int *'
 warning: format '%I64d' expects type 'int *', but argument 4 has type 'long long int *'
```

To correct it, replace `%I64d` with `%Ld`.

> but I think I'm loosing the battle with the bigger numbers...

Of course your recursive solution can make the stack overflow; for a program that demands less stack space, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27336591/2413201).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I am not understanding the problem correctly, but here are two different iterative approaches.  Maybe this could help you along:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int old_task( long a, long b, long c )
{
   size_t iteration;
   long left = a, right = b;
   for( iteration = 0; ( left < c ) && ( right < c ); ++iteration )
   {
      printf( "NOT %ld: %ld, %ld < %ld\n", iteration, left, right, c );
      if( iteration % 2 )
         left += right;
      else
         right += left;
   }
   printf( "STOP %ld: %ld, %ld < %ld\n", iteration, left, right, c );
   return ( ( left == c ) || ( right == c ) ) ? 1 : 0;
}

int task( long a, long b, long c )
{
    long f;
    /*long i = 0;*/
    for( f = a; f < c; f+= a )
    {
        /*printf( "Checking: %li * %li + %li * %li == %li\n", a, ++i, b, ( c - f ) / b, c );*/
        if( ( c - f ) % b == 0 )
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   long a,b,c;
   scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&a,&b,&c); //scaning

   printf( "%s\n\n", task( a, b, c ) ? "YES" : "NO" );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the -1?  Please explain.

Comment: I explained in the above comments.

Comment: "What I need help is, I need it to work better, and faster, and I don't know how to optimise it more."  If very explicitly asking for HOW to optimize.  I didn't think that would warrant a down vote though...

Comment: My iterative answer to the previous question I linked above, although voted +1 was incorrect, as was pointed out to me. It needs an optimized recursive solution. The answer from JS1 was much better, so feel free to downvote me there please.

Comment: The problem you linked has a different description to the problem than this poorly worded one.  But how is this not an n * a + m * b = c  problem?

Comment: As far as I read, they are the same, even the limit 10^18, the same homework. A comment to my incorrect iterative answer there was "Now, a=5, b=6, c=22 returns YES, but there is no way of reaching 22, so the answer should be NO. –JS1."

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis - as an example (I think), if a=4 and b=10, you can't get to 42. 3*a + 3*b is unreachable. Some combinations are unreachable because of the constraint of choosing adding a to b or b to a. It's not the same as choosing arbitrary values of m and n.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see what you mean now.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis The point I missed was that a or b change with each operation. You can see that in this OP example. That's why not m x a + n x b.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be solved with linear algebra.
Let's say you've got a = 3, b = 4 and c = 15. So what you're looking for is

```
3x + 4y = 15
x = (15-4y) / 3
```

So if you divide it with 3 it should have no remainder. And I think here comes linear algebra, because
15-4y should be 0 modulo 3.

It's just an idea.

Comment: I think this might return false positive answers.

Comment: But you dont deny that it would give the right ones as well?

Comment: No I don't deny that. But simply always saying true would give the right ones as well. I think a complete answer says true only if, and always when the actual answer is true.

Comment: I get you, but as I mentioned, "It's just an idea". If it gives true whenever it's supposed to do, and gives true when it should give false only in a few times, it's quite easy and cheap(comapered to recursion) to check whether it's a good or not.